# Thymeleaf form array with default values

Tags: spring, forms, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring+Thymeleaf to see and modify the users in a database. I would like to set the input fields to the actual values of an original user but I've tried with different styles and it doesn't work.

With the present configuration I can update information of users and see the id of original user (it's not in a input field) but I can't show the actual configuration in input field as default.

CONTROLLER:

```java
@GetMapping(value = {"/", ""})
public String subusersPage(HttpSession session, Model model) {
    String idUser = BaseController.getLoggedUser(session);
    UserDTO userDTO = userService.getUserById(idUser);
    model.addAttribute("subusersDTO", userService.getSubusersDTO(userDTO.getSubusers()));
    model.addAttribute("populations", userDTO.getPopulations());
    model.addAttribute("configurations", userDTO.getConfigurations());
    model.addAttribute("attributes", userDTO.getAttributes());
    model.addAttribute("subuserDTO", new SubuserDTO());
    return "subusers";
}
```

HTML:

```
<th:block th:each="subuserDTO_original : ${subusersDTO}">
    <hr>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/subusers/__${subuserDTO_original.id}__}" th:object="${subuserDTO}" method="post">
        <div>
            <p th:text="${'Id: ' + subuserDTO_original.id}"></p>
            <p>Name:            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"           th:name="name"          th:value="${subuserDTO_original.name}"/></p>
            <p>Population:      <input type="text" th:field="*{population}"     th:name="population"    th:value="${subuserDTO_original.population}"/></p>
            <p>Configuration:   <input type="text" th:field="*{configuration}"  th:name="configuration" th:value="${subuserDTO_original.configuration}"/></p>
            <p>Attributes:      <input type="text" th:field="*{attributes}"     th:name="attributes"    th:value="${subuserDTO_original.attributes}"/></p>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" th:name="action" th:value="update">Update</button>
                <button type="submit" th:name="action" th:value="delete">Delete</button>
                <button type="reset" th:name="action" th:value="clear">Clear</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/subusers/__${subuserDTO_original.id}__}" method="get">
        <button type="submit">Default</button>
    </form>
</th:block>
```

Any help will be very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to edit an existing user, then your `th:object` (which is `${subuserDTO}` in this case) needs to be populated with the values of the original user.  This is because when you use the attribute `th:field="*{name}"`, it actually overwrites the `name`, `id`, and `value` of the html tag (which is why `th:value="${subuserDTO_original.name}"` isn't working.

Two other options you could do:

1. You could also set `name="name"` and use `th:value` instead.
2. Or another option, you could use `${subuserDTO_original}` as your `th:object`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks to your comment I have realized that you can replace the ```th:field``` tag with ```id``` and ```name``` and they act in the same way, without the problem of overwriting the ```value``` tag.